# exporting raster layer in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster, r-sp, geotiff

I am working on the `bnspatial` [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnspatial/vignettes/bnspatial.html) and I would like to see what is actually within the imported data `ConwyData`:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("RBGL")
install.packages("bnspatial")
install.packages("raster")
library(raster)
library(bnspatial)
data(ConwyData)

> str(ConwyData)
List of 6
 $ ConwyStatus  :Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  .. ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ name        : chr "E:\\masanda\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.4\\bnspatial\\extdata\\ConwyStatus.tif"
```

Therefore, I want to export the file the Rater Layer into a format that i can import into ArcGis or QGIS. I have tried the following, but none of there work:

1. > writeRaster(ConwyData, "raster_bnspatial", format = "GTiff")
   >           Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
   >             unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"list", "character"’
2. > ConwyData <- file("C:/Users/admin/Dropbox/KU_Leuven/Thesis/R-scripts/ConwyData.grd", package="raster")
   >   Error in file("C:/Users/admin/Dropbox/KU_Leuven/Thesis/R-scripts/ConwyData.grd",  : 
   >     unused argument (package = "raster")

   [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnspatial/vignettes/bnspatial.html): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnspatial/vignettes/bnspatial.html

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `ConwyData` is a list of objects, rather than a single raster. That's also why you can't write it as raster to disk.

Looking at the [example documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnspatial/vignettes/bnspatial.html) (or at `?ConwyData`), the list contains the following elements:

> - LandUseChange An object of class grain. The Bayesian network, built for demonstration purposes.
> - ConwyLU An object of class RasterLayer. A simplified version of the current land use map from the Conwy catchment (Wales, UK). It includes three classes: arable (raster value 3), forest (2), other (1).
> - ConwySlope An object of class RasterLayer. A raster of slope derived from a digital elevation model at 50 meters resolution, units are degrees.
> - ConwyStatus An object of class RasterLayer. The land ownership type (dummy data), divided into three possible classes: public (raster value 4), private (3), protected (1).
> - evidence A matrix. The collection of available spatial data (see above) as extracted from each location (i.e. cell) in the catchment, where the latter is represented by the raster object ConwyLU. Each value from the spatial data was discretized through dataDiscretize or bulkDiscretize functions, then assigned to the corresponding state from the Bayesian network (LandUseChange).
> - LUclasses A list with the classification of input spatial data (its corresponding states and values). The list is formatted accordingly to bnspatial functions requirement and as returned by functions importClasses and setClasses.

As you can see, only a coupe of these are actual rasters. These you can easily write to disk:

```
writeRaster(ConwyData$ConwyLU,'/tmp/landuse.tif')
```

But if you only want to have a look, you can skip the writing to file and just visualize it with R with e.g.

`base` plotting:

```
plot(ConwyData$ConwyLU)
```

[image]

or the more versatile `rasterVis`:

```
library(rasterVis)

levelplot(ConwyData$ConwySlope,margin=FALSE)
```

[image]